# How to get product view count in prestashop

Tags: product, prestashop

how to get product view count in prestashop.

my code is

\themes\default\product.tpl

```
{php}

     function getTotalViewed1($id_product)
    {
        $view1 = Db::getInstance()->getRow('
        SELECT SUM(pv.`counter`) AS total
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'page_viewed` pv
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'date_range` dr ON pv.`id_date_range` = dr.`id_date_range`
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'page` p ON pv.`id_page` = p.`id_page`
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'page_type` pt ON pt.`id_page_type` = p.`id_page_type`
        WHERE pt.`name` = \'product.php\'
        AND p.`id_object` = '.intval($id_product).'');
        return isset($view1['total']) ? $view1['total'] : 0;
    }

        if ($id_product = intval(Tools::getValue('id_product')))
        {
            $product = new Product($id_product, false, intval($cookie->id_lang));
            $totalViewed1 = getTotalViewed1($product->id);
            echo $totalViewed1;            
        }

{/php}
```

when i use above code , page shows empty screen.

what is the issue ?

Thanks,
Karthick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function getTotalViewed1($id_product)
{
    $view1 = Db::getInstance()->getRow('
    SELECT SUM(pv.`counter`) AS total
    FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'page_viewed` pv
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'date_range` dr ON pv.`id_date_range` = dr.`id_date_range`
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'page` p ON pv.`id_page` = p.`id_page`
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'page_type` pt ON pt.`id_page_type` = p.`id_page_type`
    WHERE pt.`name` = \'product.php\'
    AND p.`id_object` = '.intval($id_product).'');
    return isset($view1['total']) ? $view1['total'] : 0;
}
```

to

```
public function getTotalViewed($id_product)
    {
        $dateBetween = ModuleGraph::getDateBetween();
        $result = Db::getInstance()->getRow('
        SELECT SUM(pv.`counter`) AS total
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'page_viewed` pv
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'date_range` dr ON pv.`id_date_range` = dr.`id_date_range`
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'page` p ON pv.`id_page` = p.`id_page`
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'page_type` pt ON pt.`id_page_type` = p.`id_page_type`
       WHERE pt.`name` = \'product.php\'
        AND p.`id_object` = '.intval($id_product).'
        AND dr.`time_start` BETWEEN '.$dateBetween.'
        AND dr.`time_end` BETWEEN '.$dateBetween.'');
        return isset($result['total']) ? $result['total'] : 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Deonia. But when i replace new code in my product.tpl file . i got blank screen only.In which file this function to placed and how to call in tpl file ?

Comment: keep this in `statsproduct.php`

Comment: Thanks @Deonia.How to display the count in product.tpl file

Answer (score -1):

1. edit     classes/Controller/FrontController.php

   ```
   public static function getTotalViewed($id_product){ 
            $view1 = Db::getInstance()->getRow('SELECT SUM(pv.counter) AS total FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'page_viewed pv 
             LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'page p ON pv.id_page = p.id_page 
             LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'page_type pt ON p.id_page_type = pt.id_page_type 
             WHERE pt.name = \'product\' AND p.`id_object` = '.intval($id_product).' group by pv.id_page'); 
             return isset($view1['total']) ? $view1['total'] : 0; 
   }
   ```
2. edit     /thems/your-theme/products.tpl

   ```
   {FrontController::getTotalViewed(Tools::getValue('id_product'))}
   ```

solved `PS 1.5.6.1`

Collect all your visitor that visit your page . pls visit this product pages